# How to create a my own com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to achieve the following in my code

```
fun addAsync(num1: Int, num2: Int): Task<Int> {
    var result: Task<Int> = //Task.fromResult(add(num1,num2))
    return result
}

fun add(num1: Int, num2:Int): Int {
    return num1+num2
}
```

here i want to know how to create a task from the result the way it is done in C#.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is use the [TaskCompletionSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource):

```kotlin
fun addAsync(num1: Int, num2: Int): Task<Int> {
    val t = TaskCompletionSource<Int>();

    // in some thread or whatever
    t.setResult(add(num1, num2))

    return t.task
}

fun add(num1: Int, num2:Int): Int {
    return num1+num2
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're a genius.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tasks.call()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#public-static-tasktresult-call-callabletresult-callable), passing an instance of Callable:

```
var result: Task<Int> = Tasks.call { 1 + 2 }
```

But that executes on the main thread.  If you want another thread, pass an Executor:

```
val result: Task<Int> = Tasks.call(someExecutor, Callable {
    1 + 2
})
```

Comment: this method has been deprecated... which should be the new right way?